# CSS make inline-block fill parent

Tags: html, css

am trying to put a `SVG` icon and some text on the same line in a menu.
I've changed the `display` from `block` to `online-block` but the text doesn't fill the parent any more.
The problem occurs when I try to `hover` an item from the menu, it activate only on a text and I want on the entire `row`.

```
#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

svg {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space: normal;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

The `HTML` part

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="#000000" d="M10,20V14H14V20H19V12H22L12,3L2,12H5V20H10Z" />
            </svg><a class="menux1" href="www.google.com">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the structure of the HTML a bit, this is the result:

```css
#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

svg {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

a li {
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space: normal;
}

a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

a { text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
        <a class="menux1" href="www.google.com"><li><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="#000000" d="M10,20V14H14V20H19V12H22L12,3L2,12H5V20H10Z" />
            </svg>Home</li></a>
</ul>
```